# How can I improve my Python code for getting the least likely positions in a 5x5 array using probability weights?

Tags: python, arrays, random, iteration, probability

I'm working on code that deals with probabilities. The error occurs on line 95. Here is the code in python

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Criar matriz 5x5
matriz = np.zeros((5, 5))

# Adicionar o histórico das últimas 10 jogadas
historico = [(1, 4, 4, 3), (0, 3, 1, 3), (3, 0, 4, 4), (2, 0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 0), (3, 3, 4, 2), (0, 1, 2, 0), (3, 3, 2, 2), (3, 1, 4, 3)]

# Excluir a primeira posição se o histórico tiver mais de 10 jogadas
if len(historico) > 10:
    historico = historico[1:]

for jogada in historico:
    x, y, x2, y2 = jogada
    if x >= 1 and x <= 5 and y >= 1 and y <= 5:
        matriz[x - 1, y - 1] = 1

# Definir parâmetros
prob_min = 0.04  # Probabilidade mínima de 4.0%
prob_max = 0.056  # Probabilidade máxima de 5.6%
num_options = 10
max_excluded_positions = 8
min_adjacent_bombs = 2

# Criar matriz de probabilidades
probabilidades = np.zeros((5, 5))

# Contar a repetição das posições e das somas das posições
posicoes_repetidas = Counter(historico)
somas_repetidas = Counter([sum(posicao) for posicao in historico])

# Atualizar as probabilidades com base no histórico e nas repetições
for linha in range(5):
    for coluna in range(5):
        posicao = (linha+1, coluna+1)
        soma = linha+1 + coluna+1

        # Atribuir peso proporcional à repetição da posição e das somas
        peso_posicao = posicoes_repetidas[posicao]  # Peso proporcional à repetição da posição
        peso_soma = somas_repetidas[soma]  # Peso proporcional à repetição da soma da posição

        # Verificar se a posição ocorreu mais de duas vezes no espaço amostral de dez jogadas
        if posicoes_repetidas[posicao] > 2:
            peso_posicao = 0  # Zerar o peso da repetição para evitar que ocorra mais de duas vezes

        # Atribuir probabilidade com base nos pesos e nas condições
        if matriz[linha, coluna] == 1:
            probabilidade = prob_max  # Probabilidade alta para posições que já tiveram bombas
        elif linha >= 1 and linha <= 3 and coluna >= 1 and coluna <= 3 and np.sum(matriz[linha-1:linha+2, coluna-1:coluna+2]) > 0:
            probabilidade = prob_max  # Probabilidade alta para posições adjacentes a posições que já tiveram bombas
        elif linha % 2 == 0 and coluna % 2 == 0:
            probabilidade = prob_max - peso_posicao * prob_min - peso_soma * prob_min  # Probabilidade média para posições pares
        else:
            probabilidade = prob_max - peso_posicao * prob_min + peso_soma * prob_min  # Probabilidade média para posições ímpares

        probabilidades[linha, coluna] = probabilidade

# Obter as coordenadas das posições disponíveis
posicoes_disponiveis = np.argwhere(matriz == 0)

# Verificar se há jogadas disponíveis suficientes
num_posicoes_disponiveis = len(posicoes_disponiveis)

if num_posicoes_disponiveis < num_options:
    print("Não há jogadas disponíveis suficientes de acordo com as restrições atuais.")
else:
    # Criar rótulos para as classes
    rótulos = np.zeros(num_posicoes_disponiveis)
    rótulos_adjacentes = np.ones(num_posicoes_disponiveis)

    # Ajustar o modelo de regressão logística para classificação
    regression = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', random_state=42, multi_class='auto')

    # Juntar as posições e rótulos
    dados = np.concatenate((posicoes_disponiveis, posicoes_disponiveis))
    rótulos_completos = np.concatenate((rótulos, rótulos_adjacentes))

    regression.fit(dados, rótulos_completos)  # Ajustar o modelo com os dados completos

    # Prever as probabilidades para todas as posições disponíveis
    probabilidades_previstas = regression.predict_proba(posicoes_disponiveis)[:, 1]

    # Ordenar as jogadas disponíveis com base nas probabilidades previstas
    jogadas_ordenadas = [(*coordenada, prob) for prob, coordenada in sorted(zip(probabilidades_previstas, posicoes_disponiveis), key=lambda x: x[0])]

    # Substituir a lista de jogadas adversárias pelo histórico
jogadas_adversario = historico

# Ajustar as probabilidades com base nas jogadas adversárias
for jogada_adv in jogadas_adversario:
    x_adv, y_adv, _, _ = jogada_adv
    for i in range(len(jogadas_ordenadas)):
        x1, y1, _, _ = jogadas_ordenadas[i]
        distancia = np.linalg.norm(np.array([x_adv, y_adv]) - np.array([x1, y1]))
        if distancia <= min_adjacent_bombs:
            x2, y2, prob = jogadas_ordenadas[i]
            jogadas_ordenadas[i] = (x1, y1, x2, y2, prob_min * (min_adjacent_bombs + 1 - distancia))



# Selecionar as próximas jogadas com menor probabilidade de haver bombas
coordenadas_jogadas = [(x1 + 1, y1 + 1, x2 + 1, y2 + 1) for (x1, y1, x2, y2, _) in jogadas_ordenadas[:num_options]]

# Imprimir a matriz
print("Matriz:")
print(matriz)

# Imprimir as próximas jogadas
print("Próximas jogadas com menor probabilidade de haver bombas:")
print(coordenadas_jogadas)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-38fbf6639a05> in <cell line: 92>()
     93     x_adv, y_adv, _, _ = jogada_adv
     94     for i in range(len(jogadas_ordenadas)):
---> 95         x1, y1, _, _ = jogadas_ordenadas[i]
     96         distancia = np.linalg.norm(np.array([x_adv, y_adv]) - np.array([x1, y1]))
     97         if distancia <= min_adjacent_bombs:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

The error is that the values ​​that the code returns are different from those that were placed.
I need the code to return a list with 10 coordinates in the format (x1,y2,x2,y2) where the lowest probabilities of having been chosen by the computer are shown